# TextView not showing under ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I do have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="75dp"
        android:paddingBottom="140dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="500.000 POINTS"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="750.000 POINTS"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
            android:text="2.000.000 POINTS" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="1.000.000 POINTS"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView4" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks. Even if it's showing in the left, it doesn't show up. I Think that it's because of padding, I tried some changes but nothing seems to work. Also If I don't set layout_marginTop for bottom TextViews they don't even show in the right screen. Here is a preview of how it looks:
[image]

Comment: put Linear layouts for every image and text that is under it and try to run the code

Answer (score 0):

At the root RelativeLayout decrease bottom padding.I made it from 140dp to 10dp, try now

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="75dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="500.000 POINTS"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="750.000 POINTS"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
        android:text="2.000.000 POINTS" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulldog" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="1.000.000 POINTS"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView4" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```